# no matching function for a function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to debug this, but can't figure out the issue here. Why is it saying no matching function for a call to `naiveGaussianElimination` even though i have passed the correct parameters?

```
void naiveGaussianElimination(int count,float doubleCoefficient[][count+1]){

}

int main() {

/*
 Read from file and assign values to vector
 */

//File stream object
ifstream inputFile;

// store file name
string fileName;

// ask user for the file name and store it
cout << "Enter the file name:>> ";
cin >> fileName;

//Open the txt file
inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

//search for the text file
if(!inputFile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Error opening file \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
    cout << "File found and successfully opened. \n";
}

/*
 find the number of variables in the equation
 */
int count =0;
string line;
while (getline(inputFile, line)){

    count++;
}
// 2D array to store augmented matrix
float doubleCoefficient [count][count+1];

/*
 assign values from text file to 2D array
 */
float value;
while(!inputFile.eof()){
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<(count+1); j++) {
            inputFile >> value;
            doubleCoefficient[i][j]=value;

        }
    }

}

// invoke naiveGaussianElimination function
    naiveGaussianElimination(count,doubleCoefficient);
```

Comment: `doubleCoefficient` isn't defined anywhere in that code sample. Also, I don't use C++ much, but is that function signature legal? Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Where are you getting the `doubleCoefficient` argument that you are passing into `naiveGaussianElimination` in `main`?

Comment: @slugonamission : I forgot to paste it here.

Comment: @TylerGaona: I forgot to paste it.

Comment: My C++-fu isn't good enough for this. I'm still wary of that function signature TBH.

Comment: I don't believe that `naiveGaussianElimination(int, float doubleCoefficient[][count+1])` is a valid declaration. I would just pass in a pointer to a pointer to a float: `naiveGaussianElimination(int, float**)`

Comment: @TylerGaona I believe it needs to know the number of columns in the 2d array at compile time.

Comment: ya, c++ needs to know the no. of columns at compile time.

Comment: You read all of the lines... then you try reading again without going back to the beginning. Not good. Also, why not use `std::vector`? Read each line, parse each line, and `push_back` the parsed data. Then you don't care about `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use dynamic array for

//2D dynamic array to store augmented matrix**

```
float **doubleCoefficient = new float*[count];
    for (int i=0; i<(count+1); i++) {
        doubleCoefficient[i] = new float[count+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you must give explicit value to declaration of multi-dimensional  array (except 1st script)  because compiler don't know what is `count` here

```
void naiveGaussianElimination(int count,float doubleCoefficient[][count+1])
                                                                    ^
```

try like this:

```
    void naiveGaussianElimination(int count,float doubleCoefficient[][4]){
      .....
    }
```

for more details check : [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html)